# How to find global direction using sensors?

Tags: accelerometer, augmented-reality, gyroscope, virtual-reality

I use an AR glass. It has some sensors such as gyroscope, accelerometer, imuOrientation and magnetometer.

I try to find real world direction(south, north etc) and position(looks sky or ground). How can I get them?

Answer (score 0):

You have magnetometer so you can use it get directions. You may need to combine it with gyroscope. It will also be handy to get position